# separating out react.js into its own file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just learning reactjs - I'm going through the tutorials.  What I can't figure out is why when I include my React script in the code it works (1st snippet).  However, when I extract the script code into a separate .js file (2nd snippet) it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
        );

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2nd Snippet:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/custom/react.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**react.js file:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As a note, I've wrapped the above js file in the `<script type="text/babel"></script>` and that didn't work either.

I've asked this in the Code Review site as well, however, I'm not sure if it belongs there or not.

As noted in a comment below, I do see a syntax error, highlighted on the `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>,` line.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes - syntax error on the  '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>,' line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try naming the file with the `.jsx` extension, and with `text/babel` type. You have to use the `.jsx` extension for Babel to know how to transpile it, which loaders to use, etc. With your current `.js` extension, Babel sees a regular JavaScript file and does not do anything, thus the error occurs. Also, include your custom script *after* your `div` because React has to wait for `root` to be loaded before it can insert anything -- and also, rename your file, it's quite confusing:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="Scripts/custom/react.jsx"></script>
```

Comment: That worked! - What if I don't use babel?  That was just from the example.  Do I have to use babel?

Comment: @webdad3 Yes. Babel allows for JSX to transpiled into regular JS the browser can understand. There are legacy options like JSXTransformer but I believe they have been deprecated for quite a while.

Comment: is that why everyone uses node?  I doesn't look like I needed to rename my files in the node examples.

Comment: @webdad3 Node would be a better choice IMO. It requires a lot more setup than this, but allows you to use a myriad of things such as newer syntax, and allows you to maintain your project much more easily.

Comment: That's the first time I've seen a reason for using node versus doing it the old school way.  That makes sense.  Thanks!